# HTML "details" element - Don't fire "toggle" event in a specific area (e.g. action buttons)

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a simple tree view for the ancestors of a person.
Displaying the data works pretty fine. Collapsing is also handled by the HTML element itself.
Each tree item has 3 action buttons.

When clicking any of those buttons, I don't want the `toggle` event of the `details` element to be fired. How can I restrict the `toggle` event to only occur when clicking outside of the 3 buttons, or maybe by only clicking the black arrow on each tree item?

[image]

```
<details *ngIf="tree" class="form-control mb-2 mt-2" open style="width: 100%; margin-left: 12.5px">
  <summary>
    {{tree?.name}} <i class="bi" [ngClass]="'bi-gender-' + tree?.sex.toLowerCase()"></i>
    <div class="btn-group float-end">
      <span class="mt-1">{{tree?.dateOfBirth}}</span>
      <a [routerLink]="['/horses/detail', tree?.id]"
         class="btn btn-sm">
        <i class="bi bi-info-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/horses/edit', tree?.id]"
         class="btn btn-sm">
        <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
      </a>
      <a (click)="deleteHorse()"
         class="btn btn-sm">
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </summary>
  <app-node [tree]="tree?.father"></app-node>
  <app-node [tree]="tree?.mother"></app-node>
</details>
```

I could not find any information on customizing the toggle and click events on the `details` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use *bootstrap*, but your issue may be caused by the buttons being regular child elements (part of the 'flow') bubbling pointer events to their parent, the `summary`. Without your CSS and a running [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is not possible for me to find out if this is true.

Instead, I created a vanilla alternative of your code which seems to meet your requirements. Simply put, I made the `summary` elements `relative` parents and `absolute` positioned the DOB and buttons.

The CSS is divided into two sections: 'Behaviour' and 'Layout'.

**Behaviour**

- Made `summary` elements a `relative` parent.
- Created a `.content` element inside `summary` to hold the birth date (`.dob`) and your button group (`.btn-group`).
- `.content` elements are positioned `absolute` inside `summary`.
- Created a 'stopper' class (`.nop`) for `details` to disable `summary` `pointer-events` when there is no deeper level of `details`.

**Layout**

The 'layout' CSS is virtually just demo code to mimic your layout in the snippet.

**snippet**

```css
/*************/
/* Behaviour */
/*************/
summary                { position: relative; width: 100% }
summary .content       { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0 }

/* Disable pointer events for (great-) grandpa, grandma */
.nop > summary         { pointer-events: none }
.nop > summary::marker { color: transparent } /* hide marker */
.nop                   { padding-left: 0 } /* mimic marker gone */

/* Reinstate pointer events for buttons */
.btn-group             { pointer-events: auto }

/* Cursor layout */
.nop > summary, summary .dob { cursor: default } /* only 'body' would work too */
summary, .btn-group > *      { cursor: pointer }


/***************************/
/* Layout, eye-candy, etc. */
/***************************/
body { font-size: 0.875rem; font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; } /* 14px */

/* prevent/enable text selection, also convenient for inadverted user multi-clicks */
[no-select],[noselect] { -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none }
[select]               { -webkit-user-select: text; -moz-user-select: text; -ms-user-select: text; user-select: text }

details {
    padding: 0.125rem 0 0.0625rem 1rem; margin: 0.5rem 0;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0,0%,0%,0.2)
}
details > details { border-right: none }
details[open]     { padding-bottom: 0 }

.C   { padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.5rem } /* Child */ 
.P   { /* parent */ } 
.GP  { /* grand parent */ } 
.GGP { /* great grand parent */ } 

/* Google material symbols outlined, gender and buttons */
[gender], [btn] {
    font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 500, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48;

    font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
    font-size  : 1.2em; line-height: 1.1;
    font-style : normal;

    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

[gender="f" i]::after { content: 'female' }
[gender="m" i]::after { content: 'male'   }

[btn]                 { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 0.125rem }
[btn="d" i]::after    { content: 'delete' }
[btn="e" i]::after    { content: 'edit' }
[btn="i" i]::after    { content: 'info' }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<details class="C" noselect>
    <summary>Child <i gender="m"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
            <span class="btn-group">
                <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </summary>

    <details class="P">
        <summary>Father <i gender="m"></i>
            <div class="content">
                <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                <span class="btn-group">
                    <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </summary>

        <details class="GP nop">
            <summary>Grandpa <i gender="m"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                    <span class="btn-group">
                        <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </summary>
        </details>
        <details class="GP nop">
            <summary>Grandma <i gender="f"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                    <span class="btn-group">
                        <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </summary>
        </details>
    </details>

    <details class="P">
        <summary>Mother <i gender="f"></i>
            <div class="content">
                <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                <span class="btn-group">
                    <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </summary>

        <details class="GP">
            <summary>Grandpa <i gender="m"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                    <span class="btn-group">
                        <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </summary>
            <details class="GGP nop">
                <summary>G-grandpa <i gender="m"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                        <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                        <span class="btn-group">
                            <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </summary>
            </details>
        </details>

        <details class="GP">
            <summary>Grandma <i gender="f"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                    <span class="btn-group">
                        <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </summary>

            <details class="GGP nop">
                <summary>G-grandpa <i gender="m"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                        <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                        <span class="btn-group">
                            <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </summary>
            </details>
            <details class="GGP nop">
                <summary>G-grandma <i gender="f"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                        <span class="dob">2023-03-10</span>
                        <span class="btn-group">
                            <a btn="i" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="e" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            <a btn="d" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </summary>
            </details>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful, now my tree is much more user friendly!