# how do I close submenus submenu on main submenu parent click

Tags: javascript, html, css, indexing, menu

I'm trying to close all submenus submenus when the submenus parent arrow element is clicked, and also rotate the arrows back. The statement that I've written does not work. it is supposed to toggle only the submenu submenus that match the Event Target. Please help.
https://jsfiddle.net/d3auwqvb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>webpage</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
      <div class="index-list">
        <ul class="index-itself">
          <li class="indexitem1 indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem1</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem1indexarrow arrow"></i>
            <ul class="indexitem1submenu index-sub-menu hidden">
              <li class="indexitem2 indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem2</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem2indexarrow arrow"></i>
                <ul class="indexitem2submenu index-sub-menu-sub-menu hidden">
                  <li><a href="#">lorem uipson</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>      
          </li>
          <li class="indexitem3 indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem3</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem1indexarrow arrow"></i>
            <ul class="indexitem3submenu index-sub-menu hidden">
              <li class="indexitem4 indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem4</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem2indexarrow arrow"></i>
                <ul class="indexitem4submenu index-sub-menu-sub-menu hidden">
                  <li><a href="#">lorem uipson</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>      
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

.index-list {
  position: static;
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-align: left;
border: 3px solid #444;
margin: 0px 105px 100px 100px;
box-shadow: #333;
background-color: #ffffff;
font-family: poppins;
font-size: 17px;
}
.index-list li {
  list-style: none;
}
.index-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.index-list li i {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.index-list .index-itself .index-sub-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.index-list li i:hover{
  font-size: 22px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.rotatearrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```
// Index //

const indexList = document.querySelector('.index-list');
const indexSubmenus = document.querySelectorAll('.index-sub-menu');
const indexSubmenusSubmenus = document.querySelectorAll('.index-sub-menu-sub-menu');

// close all submenu submenus and arrows on submenu arrow click //
indexSubmenus.forEach(submenu =>{
indexSubmenusSubmenus.forEach(submenuSubmenu =>{
submenu.parentElement.children[1].addEventListener('click',(Event)=>{
  if (submenuSubmenu.parentElement.parentElement == Event.target.parentElement){
  this.classList.add('hidden');
  this.parentElement.children[1].classList.remove('rotatearrow')}
    });
  });
});

//

// open submenus and submenu submenus //
openSubmenus = (Event)=>{
  for(let i=0; i < indexSubmenus.length; i++)
  if(indexSubmenus[i].parentElement.children[1] == Event.target){
    Event.target.parentElement.children[2].classList.toggle('hidden');
    Event.target.parentElement.children[1].classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
  }};
openSubmenusSubmenus = (Event)=>{
  for(let i=0; i < indexSubmenusSubmenus.length; i++)
  if(indexSubmenusSubmenus[i].parentElement.children[1] == Event.target){
    Event.target.parentElement.children[2].classList.toggle('hidden');
    Event.target.parentElement.children[1].classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
}};

indexList.addEventListener('click',openSubmenus);
indexList.addEventListener('click',openSubmenusSubmenus);

//
```

i tried this Javascript and this does not work:

```
indexSubmenus.forEach(submenu =>{
indexSubmenusSubmenus.forEach(submenuSubmenu =>{
submenu.parentElement.children[1].addEventListener('click',(Event)=>{
  if (submenuSubmenu.parentElement.parentElement === Event.target.parentElement){
  this.classList.add('hidden');
  this.parentElement.children[1].classList.remove('rotatearrow')}
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You really(!) need to consider using [Details Disclosure Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). Easily manipulate their layout and, best of all, they can be nested. No use of JS required... Here's my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75691948) showing the use of `<details>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't do it with preserving the class `.hidden` however the HTML attribute hidden has similar effects.

So here is my solution:

```
// Index //

const indexList = document.querySelector('.index-list');
const indexSubmenus = document.querySelectorAll('.index-sub-menu');
const indexSubmenusSubmenus = document.querySelectorAll('.index-sub-menu-sub-menu');

// close all submenu submenus and arrows on submenu arrow click //
indexSubmenus.forEach(submenu => {
  indexSubmenusSubmenus.forEach(submenuSubmenu => {
    submenu.parentElement.children[1].addEventListener('click', (Event) => {
      if (submenuSubmenu.parentElement.parentElement == Event.target.parentElement) {
        this.setAttribute('hidden', '');
        this.parentElement.children[1].classList.remove('rotatearrow');
      }
    });
  });
});

//

// open submenus and submenu submenus //
openSubmenus = (Event) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < indexSubmenus.length; i++) {
    if (indexSubmenus[i].parentElement.children[1] == Event.target) {
      if (!Event.target.parentElement.children[2].children[0].children[2].hasAttribute('hidden')) {
                Event.target.parentElement.children[2].children[0].children[2].setAttribute('hidden','')
        }
      if(Event.target.parentElement.children[2].hasAttribute('hidden')){
        Event.target.parentElement.children[2].removeAttribute('hidden');
      }
      else{
        Event.target.parentElement.children[2].setAttribute('hidden', '');
      }
      Event.target.parentElement.children[1].classList.toggle('rotatearrow');

    }
  }
};
openSubmenusSubmenus = (Event) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < indexSubmenusSubmenus.length; i++)
    if (indexSubmenusSubmenus[i].parentElement.children[1] == Event.target) {
      if(Event.target.parentElement.children[2].hasAttribute('hidden')){
        Event.target.parentElement.children[2].removeAttribute('hidden');
      }
      else{
        Event.target.parentElement.children[2].setAttribute('hidden','');
      }
      Event.target.parentElement.children[1].classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
    }
};

indexList.addEventListener('click', openSubmenus);
indexList.addEventListener('click', openSubmenusSubmenus);
```

The problem when I tried to do it with class `.hidden` was to identify the status whether it is active or not. I tried with `hasAtrribute("class","hidden")` but it didn't work (probably because the element has many classes). Someone may suggest how to do it.
Unless you want to preserve `.hidden`, this code does what you asked for.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: on the else statement, why do you have to use empty single quotes for it to work?

Comment: Also why did you have to include .children[0] in the if statement?

Comment: For `setAttribute()` to work, two parameters are required, attribute name and attribute value. But for the attribute hidden, it works without any attribute value. However we have to add something as the second parameter for `setAttribute()` to work.

Comment: For your second question, see your HTML code. `<ul>` containing 'lorem uipson' is a child of `<li>`, and a grandchild of 'grandparent' `<ul>`, not a direct child.